# Word bypass password protected files

Tags: powershell, ms-word

**PURPOSE**

The script should iterate through each file in a folder, convert to .txt and upload text to Azure database

**PROBLEM**

Everything works fine up until it hits a password protected file, I just want to skip these files. I am running this on hundreds of thousands of documents and the script will pause if it hits a password protected file until you either enter the password or click Cancel.

**SCRIPT**

```
Write-Output "Processing: $($file)"
Try {
    $doc = $word.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog($file)
}
Catch {

}

if ($doc) {
    $fileName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $fileName = $filename + ".txt"
    $doc.SaveAs("$env:TEMP\$fileName", [ref]$saveFormat)
    $doc.Close()


    $4ID = $fileName.split('-')[-1].replace(' ', '').replace(".txt", "")
    $text = Get-Content -raw "$env:TEMP\$fileName"
    $text = $text.replace("'", "")

    $query += "
    ('$text', $4ID),"
    Remove-Item -Force "$env:TEMP\$fileName"
}
```

**SOLUTION**

For anyone having the same issue, the solution was to pass a non empty string to the open call like so:

```
$wd.Documents.Open($file, $false, $falsel, $false, "ttt")
```

rather than

```
$wd.Documents.Open($file, $false, $falsel, $false, "")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a demo script of indicating if a Word document is password protected in the current directory. If the file opening doesn't get triggered by the `catch` block, continue your logic in the `try` block.

```
$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$files = Get-ChildItem $dir -Include *.doc, *.docx -Recurse

foreach ($file in $files) {
    try {
        $doc = $wd.Documents.Open($file, $null, $null, $null, "")
    } catch {
        Write-Host "$file is password-protected!"
    }
}
```

You will need to integrate the rest of your logic if you choose this approach, but it shows the general idea of checking password protected files.

Comment: Had to change $file to $file.fullname in the Open call to get this to run. Unfortunately, this still pauses the script execution as the catch block doesn't trigger until you click cancel on the password prompt.

Comment: @OwainEsau I'm not sure why it would do that for you. Perhaps you can try some of the approaches in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389528/how-to-check-if-a-word-file-has-a-password) answer.

Comment: Hi, I have been through all of those suggestions. If it runs it always tries to open the file and hangs.

Comment: Do you know what Word versions you are trying to open?

Comment: Office 365 - Word V 16.0.9126.2295 - 32 bit

Comment: All the files were updated to the newest format, also tried as a .doc file rather than docx

Comment: Figured it out, i had to change $wd.Documents.Open($file, $null, $null, $null, "")  to $wd.Documents.Open($file, $false, $falsel, $false, "ttt") not sure why but word was opening when an empty string was used as the password.

Comment: @OwainEsau Sorry I'm pretty rusty and powershell and don't use it often. Would explain why I missed that. Glad to hear it solved your problem.

Comment: Here's the documentation on the Open methid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open