# How to check if xlsx file is password protected or not using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to check if xlsx file is password protected or not. we can check for xls file as follows

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Book1.xls"));
            POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(poifs);
            Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

            try {
                if (!d.verifyPassword(Decryptor.DEFAULT_PASSWORD)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
                }

                InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(poifs);
                HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
                // parse dataStream

            } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
            }
```

But the above code works for only xls not for xlsx.

Comment: `But the above code works for only xls not for xlsx.` This sentence alone isn't helpful at all. If you get exceptions, then post them. And please describe your problem a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

First,

```
public boolean isEncrypted(String path) {

    try {
        try {
            new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        System.out.println("protected");
        return true;
    } catch (OfficeXmlFileException e) {
        System.out.println("not protected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

then,

```
if (isEncrypted(sourcepath)) {
        org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("1234");
        POIFSFileSystem filesystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(inpFn));
        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem);
        Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

        if (!d.verifyPassword("1234")) {
            System.out.println("Not good");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good!");
        }

        in = d.getDataStream(filesystem);
    } else {
        in = new FileInputStream(inpFn);
    }
    try {
        XSSFWorkbook wbIn = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what you have, but you know the password, then you should use [WorkbookFactory.create](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) and pass the password to it, eg

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("protected.xls"),
                                     "NiceSecurePassword");
```

`WorkbookFactory` will identify the type, then call the appropriate decryption and workbook loading for you. If the file isn't protected, the password will be ignored

.

If you know for sure that the file is `.xlsx` based, but aren't sure if it is protected or not, then you can do something like:

```
Workbook wb = null;
try {
   wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsx"));
} catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
   // Password protected, try to decrypt and load
}
```

If you give the XSSFWorkbook a password protected `.xlsx` file, it'll throw a [EncryptedDocumentException](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException.html) which you can catch and then try decrypting, based on the code you've already got

Comment: Does this still work for you with apache poi 3.16? I am getting a OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException. I am using Tika mime detection instead, where the mime-type is detected as "application/x-tika-ooxml-protected". Bonus for me: protected Docx is detected too.

Comment: @beat On 3.16 you're much better off just using the new WorkbookFactory methods that take a password!

Comment: problem is, i do not have the password and just have to reject uploaded files which are password protected (because the recipient will not be able to open them)

Comment: @beat Just use WorkbookFactory with an empty password string, and catch the `EncryptedDocumentException` that will throw

Comment: Just seen your edit, if it is unprotected then the password is ignored. I will probably still use the Tika approach. As far as I can see in Tika detection code, the Workbook will not be decrypted / loaded. Performance-wise this will be better for me as I do not need the content, just reject on password protection.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
```

From Apache POI: "HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format. XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format." http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/ You're using the HSSF (which will work for xls) on a XLSX file.