# How to know excel is password protected or not

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to detect excel(xls and xlsx) file is password protected? is there any flag to check?
Note: there are 2 types to give password to the excel(xls/xlsx):

1. Password protected (excel->save as->Tools->general option )
2. Password encrypted (excel->File permissin->encrypt)

My code is working for only xls with password encrypted.

1. xls encrypted-EncryptedDocumentException -pass(proper exception )
2. xls password protected -IllegalArgumentException-fail(general exception)
3. xlsx encrypted-POIXMLException-fail(general exception)
4. xlsx password protected -POIXMLException-fail(general exception)

For above failed cases instead of general exception I want to improve this code.

Jars used:

poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar

poi-3.7-20101029.jar

poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar

```
       public static String excelFileScanner(InputStream excelFileToScan, 
       String  uploadFileExt) throws IOException {
    String returnStatus = null;
    try {

        Workbook wb = null;// WorkbookFactory.create(excelFileToScan);
        if (uploadFileExt.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFileToScan);
        } else {
            // POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(excelFileToScan);
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFileToScan);
        }

        int noOfSheet = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfSheet; i++) {
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                        return "malicious";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        returnStatus = "valid";
    } catch (POIXMLException ex1) {
        // catch (InvalidFormatException ex1) {
        returnStatus = ex1.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if (ex1 != null && ex1.getCause() != null) {

            System.out.println("reason: " + ex1.getCause().toString());

            System.out.println("passwordprotected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("else block: " + ex1);
        }

    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException ex2) {
        returnStatus = "passwordProtected";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        returnStatus = ex.getMessage();

    }

    return returnStatus;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        File folder = new File("/Desktop/Excel/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                String uploadFileExt = null;
                String filename = file.getName();
                int extnSeparatorIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
                if (extnSeparatorIndex != -1) {
                    if (extnSeparatorIndex != file.length() - 1) {
                        uploadFileExt = filename.substring(extnSeparatorIndex + 1);
                    }
                    // String uploadFileExt = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    InputStream fileUploaded = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("extension:  " + uploadFileExt);
                    String returnStatus= PasswordExcelRead.excelFileScanner(fileUploaded, uploadFileExt);
                    System.out.println("Final: " + returnStatus);


                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28645380/7109162

Comment: Do some research. Read the documentation of the API you are using. See [ask] and [help].

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#isRevisionLocked--

Comment: @zabuza after some research i have updated the question kindly help me with this .

Comment: @ojal: the mixed jar versions you are using are so 1999, how about using POI 3.17? ...  and don't mix the versions

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would catch `EncryptedDocumentException` to check whether a file is password protected or not:

```
InputStream input = ...
Workbook wb;
try {
    wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input)
} catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
   // password protected
}
```

Comment: I have a question. I know there is a try/catch but there is not a boolean value?

Comment: There's a default password, i.e. the one which is used, if you don't specify a password when encrypting. So in this case the WorkbookFactory.create () will be successful, as we try the default password as a fallback

Comment: It is working for only encrypted xls files.. please have a look at updated question..