# How to open the excel file through c#,File may be password protected or may not be?

Tags: c#, excel

please read the following details because my scenarios are different.

My project need the small functionality of reading data from excel file and writing data to excel file through c#.

I am providing the two options for user
1. Create Excel file
2.Open Existing excel file

if user select option 1
then it will ask to user that does he want to protect file by setting password or not

1.set password
2.No I don't want to set password

in this way my file will be saved.(please consider file path is already given)

now if user want to open the file then i need to check whether the file is password protected or not.

if file is password protected I want to ask for pass, otherwise not

problem is that--I want to check the file is password protected or not.
I tried that by using 'HasPassword' property of WorkBook

```
if(WorkBookObj.HasPassword)
{
//ask for pass and call method with pass
 ExcelFileObj.OpenExcelFile(UserEnteredPath,userEnteredPass);
}
else 
{
//no need to ask for pass
ExcelFileObj.OpenExcelFile(UserEnteredPath);
}
```

I did code like above

OpenExcel file method is like this

```
public void OpenExcelFile(FilePath,string password)
        {
            try
            {
                XlWorkbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, Password: password);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw new Exception(e.Message);

            }
        }
```

like wise i also have the another overloaded method OpenExcelFile(filePath)

I came to know that HasPassword only work when File is open. But I want that before opening the file because I want to call different method depending upon the value of HasPassword property. Please suggest some solution for this.

what i tried---i was trying to solve that by catching the exception which is thrown by this Method

```
 XlWorkbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, Password: password);
```

firstly I called the overloaded Open(Password) method if the file is password protected it will through exception and i can do my stuff (i.e asking to user for pass)
but here problem is that

```
XlWorkbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, Password: password);
```

this method can though different exception
like file not found,
password is not correct etc
these all are of type  "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"
so I can not use multiple catch statement to catch different type of exception like
"System.Io.FileNotFoundException",....etc
if I try to do that it will say exception class must be Inherited from System.Exception.
so please suggest any solution for this.

or is there any unique thing (like ErrorCode..etc)which will differentiate the two exception 
like file not found,
password is not correct etc

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You could open the Excel without visibility first, couldn’t you? … or try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778074/detecting-a-password-protected-document.

Comment: Save yourself some pain. If you have any control over your requirements, restrict your support to the Office 2007+ formats, so you can work with Office Open XML. If you have someone paying you, calmly introduce them to huge extra costs in case they love their *.xls files for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks @HugoUchoBruno     ...I was trying that but it was showing some problem...but I checked once again and correct the error now its working fine

Comment: Thanks @grek40 .....issue is solved now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting a password-protected document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778074/detecting-a-password-protected-document)